# Querying a Sitecore Droplink field

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

The following Sitecore query works for me in the XPath Builder:

```
/sitecore/content/Home/CareAndTreatment//*[@Title='Birth Marks and other skin conditions']
```

But a similar query that checks on a DropLink field instead of a Single-Line Text field does not return any results:

```
/sitecore/content/Home/CareAndTreatment//*[@TreatmentType='Conditions']
```

Is there a syntax difference in the query language for Single-Line Text versus Droplink?

[NOTE: These examples use Sitecore 6.2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could be wrong, but... Isn't the DropLink field storing the item ID rather than the text?  So you'd have to query against that.

DropList - stores text as raw value
DropLink - stores ID as raw value

Maybe the Query API takes this into account?

Answer (score 3):

The solution is not that hard, prefix it with query, e.g.:

```
query:/sitecore/content/Home/CareAndTreatment//*[@TreatmentType='Conditions']
```

See also: http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Data%20Definition%20Cookbook.aspx
(2.4.2)

Comment: Sitecore makes this confusing. I am using the XPath Builder to test queries (Developer Center -> Tools -> XPath Builder) and it does not work if you type "query:" at the start. If you do, it says "End of string expected at position 5." I know the tool works because the first query works.

Comment: If you're testing a Sitecore query from dev centre, you don't need the "query:" portion as this is implied. Just put whatever you would after this.